# Where is the IOTA-Data-MarketPlace API?

Tags: iota-network, iri-legacy-api

Is the IOTA-Data-MarketPlace API available?
At the moment it looks like only the transactions API is available, correct?

Comment: Can you clarify what what you mean by *the IOT API interface* ?

Comment: at the moment, using the api I can create and monitor iota crypto transactions, but how can I store and retrieve my weather station data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the DataMarketPlace API isn't public yet. The DataMarketPlace IXI is currently running on the test-net and API is still under private testing.